# Parsing a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to parse the following nested dictionary for all URL entries. They should be written into a `list`:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('56a22819ffd6f'),
 u'books': [{u'id': {u'id': u'4311'},
   u'link': {u'name': u'Operating Business',
    u'url': u'http://ffff'}},
  {u'id': {u'id': u'4310'},
   u'link': {u'name': u'Operating Business',
    u'url': u'http://zzzzz'}},
  {u'id': {u'id': u'7462'},
   u'link': {u'name': u'European Credit Trading',
    u'url': u'http://xxxx'}},
  {u'id': {u'id': u'3258'},
   u'link': {u'name': u'Operating Business',
    u'url': u'http://dddddd'}},
  {u'id': {u'id': u'7463'},
   u'link': {u'name': u'US Credit Trading',
    u'url': u'http://aaaaa'}}],
 u'created': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 13, 1, 12, 744000),
 u'id': u'lingering-smoke',
 u'valuationDate': datetime.datetime(170, 1, 1, 0, 0, 16, 821000)}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the same `variables` used by @gkusner a alternative approach to solve it, e.g.

```
>>> dd = {full dictionary}
>>> [ll['link']['url'] for ll in ['books']]
[u'http://ffff', u'http://zzzzz', u'http://xxxx', u'http://dddddd', u'http://aaaaa']
```

Comment: this is certainly a correct solution - only downside is list comprehension can be hard to understand for a beginner - and i was trying to get answer in first :}

Answer (score 2):

let dd = dict

```
dd = {full dictionary}
url_list = []
for ll in dd['books']:
    url_list.append(ll['link']['url'])

print url_list

[u'http://ffff', u'http://zzzzz', u'http://xxxx', u'http://dddddd', u'http://aaaaa']
```

Comment: You have missed `:` in your `for`.